# limit cpu and memory consumption of all X applications

Tags: cgroups, x

I want to reserve a small amount of cpu and memory to be able in case of emergency create tty session and kill a memory hogging X application. [cgroups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt) provide this functionality. How do I put all my X applications inside cgroup automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Debian, so the solution is based on `systemd` cgroup implementation.

The first step is to inspect the cgroups hierarchy:

```bsh
> systemd-cgls
-.slice
├─user.slice
│ └─user-1000.slice
│   ├─user@1000.service
.....
│   └─session-2.scope
│     ├─1376 lightdm --session-child 14 21
│     ├─1400 x-window-manager
.....
```

`systemd` automatically assigns cgroups to terminal sessions. In cgroup hierarchy we need determine which `session-*.scope` has X applications in it. Default X session scope number is always the same.

To set memory limit to all programs in a scope, type

```bsh
> systemctl set-property session-2.scope MemoryLimit=14G
```

This command sets memory limit to the session 2 until reboot.

To make this rule permanent, run

```bsh
> sudo systemctl edit session-2.scope
```

in text editor type

```
[Scope]
MemoryLimit=14G
```

and save. This rule will persist between reboots.
Other resource limits may be set in a same file.

---

## Edit

As derobert pointed out, X session scope number is not guarantied to be the same. More robust solution is to determine this number at runtime.

File `/usr/local/bin/resource_limit.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for s in $(systemd-cgls --no-pager --user-unit \
           | grep --extended-regexp --only-matching \
              'session-.{1,3}\.scope');do
    systemctl set-property --runtime "$s" MemoryLimit="$1"
done
```

File `/etc/systemd/system/resource_limit.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Limit resources
Requires=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/resource_limit.sh 14G
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/resource_limit.sh 20G
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Copy files above to your system and issue command

```bsh
systemctl daemon-reload
```

After this you may set specified limit (in this case 14G) using command

```bsh
systemctl start resource_limit.service
```

and unset it (setting some higher limit value) using command

```bsh
systemctl stop resource_limit.service
```

In order to run this script on reboot automatically, issue command

```bsh
systemctl enable resource_limit.service
```

#### Note 1

If your X session does not start fast enough, you may want to increase service delay via `ExecStartPre` or enable service manually.

#### Note 2

It is a good idea to also add restrictions to `user@1000.service` (where 1000 - is a UID) with slightly bigger limit. This way you will always have resources available for system daemons.

Comment: It's just session 2 because they're assigned in order. Here my X session is 4 (also Debian). So you unfortunately can't consistently target the X session by name. You can get a list of sessions from `loginctl list-sessions`, so I bet it's possible to do it with some scripting.

Comment: @derobert the command `loginctl --no-pager --no-legend --property=session list-sessions` should do what you desribe, but it looks like the CLI does not respect the `--property=` part